# I don´t find the mistake SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: pdo

Please coders, i don´t find the mistake. Changes are not saved. I have two saving options, one for a customer and the second one, i can choose this customer and extend the datafields and want to save this in a second table. But i dont know, what is wrong here.

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
include_once 'header.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
{
 $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
 $fname = $_POST['first_name'];
 $streetnr = $_POST['streetnr'];
 $mail = $_POST['mail'];
 $mobil = $_POST['mobil'];
 $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
 $pcity = $_POST['pcity'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $fax = $_POST['fax'];
 $company = $_POST['company'];
 $date = $_POST['date'];
 $ticketnr = $_POST['ticketnr'];
 $partner = $_POST['partner'];
 $article_1 = $_POST['article_1'];
 $pieces_1 = $_POST['pieces_1'];
 $reason_1 = $_POST['reason_1'];
 $action_1 = $_POST['action_1'];
 $article_2 = $_POST['article_2'];
 $pieces_2 = $_POST['pieces_2'];
 $reason_2 = $_POST['reason_2'];
 $action_2 = $_POST['action_2'];
 $article_3 = $_POST['article_3'];
 $pieces_3 = $_POST['pieces_3'];
 $reason_3 = $_POST['reason_3'];
 $action_3 = $_POST['action_3'];
 $article_4 = $_POST['article_4'];
 $pieces_4 = $_POST['pieces_4'];
 $reason_4 = $_POST['reason_4'];
 $action_4 = $_POST['action_4'];
 $article_5 = $_POST['article_5'];
 $pieces_5 = $_POST['pieces_5'];
 $reason_5 = $_POST['reason_5'];
 $action_5 = $_POST['action_5'];
 $article_6 = $_POST['article_6'];
 $pieces_6 = $_POST['pieces_6'];
 $reason_6 = $_POST['reason_6'];
 $action_6 = $_POST['action_6'];
 $article_7 = $_POST['article_7'];
 $pieces_7 = $_POST['pieces_7'];
 $reason_7 = $_POST['reason_7'];
 $action_7 = $_POST['action_7'];
 $article_8 = $_POST['article_8'];
 $pieces_8 = $_POST['pieces_8'];
 $reason_8 = $_POST['reason_8'];
 $action_8 = $_POST['action_8'];
 $article_9 = $_POST['article_9'];
 $pieces_9 = $_POST['pieces_9'];
 $reason_9 = $_POST['reason_9'];
 $action_9 = $_POST['action_9'];
 $article_10 = $_POST['article_10'];
 $pieces_10 = $_POST['pieces_10'];
 $reason_10 = $_POST['reason_10'];
 $action_10 = $_POST['action_10'];
 $status = $_POST['status'];

 if($crud->update_complaint($id,$fname,$streetnr,$lname,$pcity,$company,$mail,$phone,$mobil,$fax,$date,$ticketnr,$partner
                            ,$article_1,$pieces_1,$reason_1,$action_1
                            ,$article_2,$pieces_2,$reason_2,$action_2
                            ,$article_3,$pieces_3,$reason_3,$action_3
                            ,$article_4,$pieces_4,$reason_4,$action_4
                            ,$article_5,$pieces_5,$reason_5,$action_5
                            ,$article_6,$pieces_6,$reason_6,$action_6
                            ,$article_7,$pieces_7,$reason_7,$action_7
                            ,$article_8,$pieces_8,$reason_8,$action_8
                            ,$article_9,$pieces_9,$reason_9,$action_9
                            ,$article_10,$pieces_10,$reason_10,$action_10
                            ,$status))
 {
  $msg = "<div class='customers'>
    Änderungen wurden gespeichert.
    </div>";
 }
 else
 {
  $msg = "<div class='customers'>
    <strong>UPS!</strong> da ist etwas schief gelaufen.
    </div>";
 }
}

if(isset($_GET['edit_id']))
{
 $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
 extract($crud->getcomplaintID($id)); 
}

?>

<p>

<div style="padding-left: 16px">


<div class="customers">
    <?php
    if(isset($msg))
    {
     echo $msg;
    }
    ?>
</div>





<form method='post'>

    <table id='customers'>

        <table id="customers" style='font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif'>

        <tr>
            <td>Vorname</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='first_name' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>" required></td>

            <td>Straße, Nr.</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='streetnr' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $streetnr; ?>" required></td>

            <td>E-Mail</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='mail' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $mail; ?>" required></td>

            <td>Mobil</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='mobil' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $mobil; ?>" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nachname</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='last_name' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>" required></td>

            <td>Plz, Ort</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='pcity' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $pcity; ?>" required></td>

            <td>Telefon</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='phone' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" required></td>

            <td>Fax</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='fax' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $fax; ?>" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Firma</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='company' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $company; ?>" ></td>
        </tr>

        </table>

        <p><hr><p>

        <table id="customers" style='font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif'>

            <tr>
                <td><b>Datum</b></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='date' size="10" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $date; ?>" required></td>

                <td><b>Ticketnummer</b></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='ticketnr' size="10" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $ticketnr; ?>" required></td>

                <td><b>Partner</b></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='partner' size="46" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $partner; ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p><hr><p>

        <table id="customers" style='font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif'>




            <tr>
                <td>Artikel 1</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='article_1' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $article_1; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Anzahl</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='pieces_1' size="2" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $pieces_1; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Grund</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='reason_1' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $reason_1; ?>" required></td>

                <td>gewünschte Aktion</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='action_1' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $action_1; ?>" required></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Artikel 2</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='article_2' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $article_2; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Anzahl</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='pieces_2' size="2" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $pieces_2; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Grund</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='reason_2' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $reason_2; ?>" required></td>

                <td>gewünschte Aktion</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='action_2' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $action_2; ?>" required></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Artikel 3</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='article_3' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $article_3; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Anzahl</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='pieces_3' size="2" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $pieces_3; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Grund</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='reason_3' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $reason_3; ?>" required></td>

                <td>gewünschte Aktion</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='action_3' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $action_3; ?>" required></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Artikel 4</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='article_4' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $article_4; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Anzahl</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='pieces_4' size="2" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $pieces_4; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Grund</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='reason_4' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $reason_4; ?>" required></td>

                <td>gewünschte Aktion</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='action_4' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $action_4; ?>" required></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Artikel 5</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='article_5' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $article_5; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Anzahl</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='pieces_5' size="2" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $pieces_5; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Grund</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='reason_5' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $reason_5; ?>" required></td>

                <td>gewünschte Aktion</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='action_5' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $action_5; ?>" required></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Artikel 6</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='article_6' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $article_6; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Anzahl</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='pieces_6' size="2" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $pieces_6; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Grund</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='reason_6' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $reason_6; ?>" required></td>

                <td>gewünschte Aktion</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='action_6' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $action_6; ?>" required></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Artikel 7</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='article_7' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $article_7; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Anzahl</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='pieces_7' size="2" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $pieces_7; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Grund</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='reason_7' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $reason_7; ?>" required></td>

                <td>gewünschte Aktion</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='action_7' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $action_7; ?>" required></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Artikel 8</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='article_8' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $article_8; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Anzahl</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='pieces_8' size="2" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $pieces_8; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Grund</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='reason_8' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $reason_8; ?>" required></td>

                <td>gewünschte Aktion</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='action_8' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $action_8; ?>" required></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Artikel 9</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='article_9' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $article_9; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Anzahl</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='pieces_9' size="2" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $pieces_9; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Grund</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='reason_9' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $reason_9; ?>" required></td>

                <td>gewünschte Aktion</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='action_9' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $action_9; ?>" required></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Artikel 10</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='article_10' size="40" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $article_10; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Anzahl</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='pieces_10' size="2" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $pieces_10; ?>" required></td>

                <td>Grund</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='reason_10' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $reason_10; ?>" required></td>

                <td>gewünschte Aktion</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='action_10' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $action_10; ?>" required></td>
            </tr>
        </table>



        <p><hr>
        <p>
        <table id="customers" style='font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif'> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type='text' name='status' size="30" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $status; ?>" required>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table><p>
        <table id="customers">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit" name="btn-update">
                        Änderung speichern
                    </button>
                    <button><a href="index_complaints.php" style="color: white">Zurück</a></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </table>



</form>
```

and here ist the section from the class.crud.php:

```
public function update_complaint($id,$fname,$streetnr,$lname,$pcity,$company,$mail,$phone,$mobil,$fax,$date,$ticketnr,$partner
                                    ,$article_1,$pieces_1,$reason_1,$action_1
                                    ,$article_2,$pieces_2,$reason_2,$action_2
                                    ,$article_3,$pieces_3,$reason_3,$action_3
                                    ,$article_4,$pieces_4,$reason_4,$action_4
                                    ,$article_5,$pieces_5,$reason_5,$action_5
                                    ,$article_6,$pieces_6,$reason_6,$action_6
                                    ,$article_7,$pieces_7,$reason_7,$action_7
                                    ,$article_8,$pieces_8,$reason_8,$action_8
                                    ,$article_9,$pieces_9,$reason_9,$action_9
                                    ,$article_10,$pieces_10,$reason_10,$action_10
                                    ,$status)
 {
  try
  {
   $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE complaints SET first_name=:fname,
                                                streetnr=:streetnr,
                                                last_name=:lname, 
                                                pcity=:pcity,
                                                company=:company,
                                                mail=:mail,
                                                phone=:phone,
                                                mobil=:mobil,
                                                fax=:fax,
                                                date=:date,
                                                ticketnr=:ticketnr,
                                                partner=:partner,
                                                article_1=:article_1,
                                                pieces_1=:pieces_1,
                                                reason_1=:reason_1,
                                                action_1=:action_1,
                                                article_2=:article_2,
                                                pieces_2=:pieces_2,
                                                reason_2=:reason_2,
                                                action_2=:action_2,
                                                article_3=:article_3,
                                                pieces_3=:pieces_3,
                                                reason_3=:reason_3,
                                                action_3=:action_3,
                                                article_4=:article_4,
                                                pieces_4=:pieces_4,
                                                reason_4=:reason_4,
                                                action_4=:action_4,
                                                article_5=:article_5,
                                                pieces_5=:pieces_5,
                                                reason_5=:reason_5,
                                                action_5=:action_5,
                                                article_6=:article_6,
                                                pieces_6=:pieces_6,
                                                reason_6=:reason_6,
                                                action_6=:action_6,
                                                article_7=:article_7,
                                                pieces_7=:pieces_7,
                                                reason_7=:reason_7,
                                                action_7=:action_7,
                                                article_8=:article_8,
                                                pieces_8=:pieces_8,
                                                reason_8=:reason_8,
                                                action_8=:action_8,
                                                article_9=:article_9,
                                                pieces_9=:pieces_9,
                                                reason_9=:reason_9,
                                                action_9=:action_9,
                                                article_10=:article_10,
                                                pieces_10=:pieces_10,
                                                reason_10=:reason_10,
                                                action_10=:action_,10,
                                                status=:status
                                            WHERE id=:id ");
   $stmt->bindparam(":fname",$fname);
   $stmt->bindparam(":streetnr",$streetnr);
   $stmt->bindparam(":lname",$lname);
   $stmt->bindparam(":pcity",$pcity);
   $stmt->bindparam(":company",$company);
   $stmt->bindparam(":mail",$mail);
   $stmt->bindparam(":phone",$phone);
   $stmt->bindparam(":mobil",$mobil);
   $stmt->bindparam(":fax",$fax);
   $stmt->bindparam(":date",$date);
   $stmt->bindparam(":ticketnr",$ticketnr);
   $stmt->bindparam(":partner",$partner);
   $stmt->bindparam(":article_1",$article_1);
   $stmt->bindparam(":pieces_1",$pieces_1);
   $stmt->bindparam(":reason_1",$reason_1);
   $stmt->bindparam(":action_1",$action_1);
   $stmt->bindparam(":article_2",$article_2);
   $stmt->bindparam(":pieces_2",$pieces_2);
   $stmt->bindparam(":reason_2",$reason_2);
   $stmt->bindparam(":action_2",$action_2);
   $stmt->bindparam(":article_3",$article_3);
   $stmt->bindparam(":pieces_3",$pieces_3);
   $stmt->bindparam(":reason_3",$reason_3);
   $stmt->bindparam(":action_3",$action_3);
   $stmt->bindparam(":article_4",$article_4);
   $stmt->bindparam(":pieces_4",$pieces_4);
   $stmt->bindparam(":reason_4",$reason_4);
   $stmt->bindparam(":action_4",$action_4);
   $stmt->bindparam(":article_5",$article_5);
   $stmt->bindparam(":pieces_5",$pieces_5);
   $stmt->bindparam(":reason_5",$reason_5);
   $stmt->bindparam(":action_5",$action_5);
   $stmt->bindparam(":article_6",$article_6);
   $stmt->bindparam(":pieces_6",$pieces_6);
   $stmt->bindparam(":reason_6",$reason_6);
   $stmt->bindparam(":action_6",$action_6);
   $stmt->bindparam(":article_7",$article_7);
   $stmt->bindparam(":pieces_7",$pieces_7);
   $stmt->bindparam(":reason_7",$reason_7);
   $stmt->bindparam(":action_7",$action_7);
   $stmt->bindparam(":article_8",$article_8);
   $stmt->bindparam(":pieces_8",$pieces_8);
   $stmt->bindparam(":reason_8",$reason_8);
   $stmt->bindparam(":action_8",$action_8);
   $stmt->bindparam(":article_9",$article_9);
   $stmt->bindparam(":pieces_9",$pieces_9);
   $stmt->bindparam(":reason_9",$reason_9);
   $stmt->bindparam(":action_9",$action_9);
   $stmt->bindparam(":article_10",$article_10);
   $stmt->bindparam(":pieces_10",$pieces_10);
   $stmt->bindparam(":reason_10",$reason_10);
   $stmt->bindparam(":action_10",$action_10);
   $stmt->bindparam(":status",$status);
   $stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
   $stmt->execute();

   return true; 
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
   echo $e->getMessage(); 
   return false;
  }
 } 

 public function getID($id)
 {
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id=:id");
  $stmt->execute(array(":id"=>$id));
  $editRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $editRow;
 }
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: If the database were properly normalised, then the query would be much better readable and the typo would have been easier to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code here:

```
action_10=:action_,10,
```

Instead of

```
action_10=:action_10,
```

The database is interpreting that as two separate values:

```
 :action_,
 10
```

It's therefore expecting you to bind a parameter called `action_`, and not a parameter called `action_10`.

(As a side note, you should read up on "database normalisation" - you can make your database much more useful by separating your repeated columns into a separate table.)

Comment: oh my god, i thank you very,very much. how have you found this mistake so fast? i have search almost two hours. and thank you for your tip with the database normalisation.

Comment: @devando A fresh pair of eyes, and a lucky spot. :)

Comment: awesome comment, i like your style. Have a nice day :D